# Washing machine E03 error

Tags: plumbing, drain, washing-machine, drainage

I have Hoover washing machine. During my last wash cycle it suddenly stopped washing and gave me **E03** error code.

> The E03 error code on your Hoover washing machine means that the drum
> isn't draining - normally this is caused by a blockage, and it only
> takes a few minutes to fix

What I did later was completely clean the drain filter. (It was already clean when I pulled it out). One thing to mention that when I pulled out the hose to drain the water, it looked like limescale came out as well with the water.

So after the cleaning, I've put everything back together but the problem persists. You can check the video here on how it sounds when I put the drain mode:

https://youtu.be/mATUkTh_w8o

Any clues on what else I could try?

Comment: It's strange that the sound repeats on a one-second period; what part of a pump would do that? I'd try and find the exact source of that sound.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a Siemens IQ500 (Error E18). A reason for that sound might be that water isn't reaching the drain pump, so it's speeding up, getting stopped and restarted every few seconds. But that's just a guess.

A few things could cause that draining error:

1. Clean the drain filter.
2. Check if the drain hose is bent. Washing machines sometimes move, so they can bend the drain hose until water cannot go through anymore.
3. Connect another hose to the drain and let some water flow through it to make sure the drain itself isn't cloaked.
4. The drain pump might be corrupted or blocked. Try turning it with your fingers (it's right behind the drain filter). Doubt that's it though since you can still hear it running.
5. The outflow of the washing drum or the pipe between washing drum and drain pump might be clogged - are you missing any socks lately? :) That'd explain the sound you're hearing - water cannot reach the drain pump. You'll have to remove the front cover to get there though. Once you've removed the pipe you should be able to see (or feel) if there's something blocking the outflow of the washing drum (also a 20 EUR WiFi endoscope camera can be very helpful for checking if there are things inside the washing drum). If there's a sock stuck in the outflow of the washing drum, you can use a piece of thin copper or steel wire to push it out (stick it through the little holes in the washing drum).

In my case the problem was caused by case 5. I pulled out 4 different things the washing machine has eaten over time.

Comment: I took everything apart and cleaned it thoroughly. It still didn’t work. I was lucky enough to find some post associating the error code with heating element issue. I ended up replacing the heating element (mine was full of scale), and the machine started working again. The error was definitely miss leading in my case...